# Alcohol in fictional story

Tags: halal-haram, alcohol, books

Salam Alaykum Brothers and sisters

So, I am an author of a web novel, and I would like to know if I can depict alcohol drinking

Ofcourse, the main character is not and I am making her personality to be one who does not drink, but the setting of the world does cause the need to depict some things as it is set in the Middle Ages.

I am also showing how the person drinking the alcohol being easily manipulated by others and also how it has a negative impact on him and also how our main character gets around this by using it to her advantage.

Is this permissible?

Comment: Why should it be haram? Could you explain what mad you think so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reminds of [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29656/is-it-permissible-to-write-a-fictional-story-in-which-there-are-non-muslim-chara).

If you have no intention of promoting bad behaviour or evil-doings, yes, write your novel. I have never come across any reason why you shouldn't. On the contrary, if I understand correctly, you are planning on showing some dangers of alcohol consumption.